# How do I use jQuery to select an input for use with .empty()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the HTML below, how can I use jQuery `.empty` to remove `<div class="password-link">` and everything inside - the `href link`, the text `Log in` and the `</a>` - as well as the closing `</div>`?

I'm trying to use

`jQuery('#lostpasswordform input#wp-submit').empty('password-link');`

but I must not be selecting the input or the form in the correct way.

```
<form name="lostpasswordform" id="lostpasswordform" action="http://localhost/~user/wp-core/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="">
     <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="">
// Remove this:
    <div class="password-link"><a href="http://localhost/~user/wp-core/wp-login.php">Log in</a></div>

    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: $("#lostpasswordform .password-link").empty()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you want to remove that element or clean the content of it

`$('.password-link').empty()` will return:

```
<div class="password-link"></div>
```

while `$('.password-link').remove()` will remove/delete that element `.password-link`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```js
$('#lostpasswordform input#wp-submit').on("click", function(){
  var $passwordlink = $(".password-link");
  $passwordlink.empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="lostpasswordform" id="lostpasswordform" action="http://localhost/~user/wp-core/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="">
     <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="">
// Remove this:
    <div class="password-link"><a href="http://localhost/~user/wp-core/wp-login.php">Log in</a></div>

    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? @BlueDogRanch

Answer (score 0):

.empty() removes the child nodes and content. So the div you want to remove should be wrapped around another div and you can call the .empty() method on that parent div.